# How do I fix the Event ID 10154 regarding SPNs?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

Server 2012 R2, Hyper-V VM-PDC w/ AD DS, DNS (single DC still; 2nd will be created shortly)

The Event ID 10154 General comments state:

```
The WinRM service failed to create the following SPNs: WSMAN/vsWBCdc01.wbc.local; WSMAN/vsWBCdc01. 

Additional Data 
The error received was 1355: %%1355.

User Action 
The SPNs can be created by an administrator using setspn.exe utility.
```

I worked with the setspn command.  I could see "WSMAN/vsWBCdc01.wbc.local and WSMAN/vsWBCdc01" were not listed for either the administrator or the server.

I added "WSMAN/vsWBCdc01.wbc.local and WSMAN/vsWBCdc01" to the server but the error remained.  I had little confidence in, but tried anyway to add them instead to the administrator account.

In both cases the 10154 EventID remains.

I guess my question is 'can I fix this error?' and 'do I need to fix this error'.  Did I misread the instructions in the event viewer?

Or is this also simply a transient error that resolves after the dynamic activity of startup completes?

Answer (score 1):

Your spns need to be added the service accounts, not the local administrator.  ADSIEdit can be really helpful in figuring out where they go.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error on the server, I have this "The SPNs can be created by an administrator using setspn.exe utility", "

The WinRM service failed to create the following SPNs: WSMAN/Server01.dominio.ck; WSMAN/Server01.

Additional Data
The error received was 1355: %%1355.
"

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/505222)